# Changing member types in inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Given a base class `Base` that has two derived classes, `DerA` and `DerB`, can the derived classes have a member variable that is used in a `Base` member function, but is a different type for each class?

```
class Base {
    * a // Declare a as *something*, so it can be used by "doWork"

    template <typedef T>
    void doWork(T b) { // Add another value to "a" which is of its same type
        a += b; // For example; an operation that works on "a", no matter what numeric type it is
    }
}

class DerA : public Base {
    // Make "a" an int
}

class DerB : public Base {
    // Make "a" a float
}
```

In practice, `a` will be a base struct, while `DerA` and `DerB` will have derived versions of the base struct (derivative classes will each have a derived form of the struct specific to their purpose, but each must do a simple operation on `a`, so it seems pointless to copy/paste that simple function for each derivative when I can just use a template function).  I would just type `a` as the base struct type, but then I lose access to the various specialized member functions and variables that each derived struct has (if I understand inheritance correctly).

I apologize if this question is a repeat, but I don't know what this quality would be called, so Googling proved fruitless.

Comment: As it is, I cannot see why is shouldnt be `template <typename T> class Der { T t; template <typename K> void doWork(K b) { a+=b;}}; typedef Der<int> DerA; typedef Der<float> DerB;}`

Comment: A better way to say my previous comment, why are you bothering with polymorphism in this case? this seems like a cut and dry application for a template class.

Comment: Do you need to pass `DerA*`s and `DerB*`s around as `Base*`s?  I hope not.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams, in practice, the classes are much more complex than shown. Forgive my lack of explanation.  You're right, templating the entire class would be useful, but I don't want to template each one if I can avoid it, especially because this is just one small function of the class.

Comment: @Yakk, I DO pass them around as pointers to the base class.  Is that bad for any other reason than it makes this particular problem difficult?

Comment: Well, it now requires double dispatch.  The type `T`s passed to `doWork`, is there a limited set of such `T`s you invoke it with?  Or is there a limited set of `Der` type classes you are willing to stick to, or list somewhere?

Comment: @Yakk, yes it is a limited list.  Unfortunately, I think that implementing CRTP is going to be more trouble than it's worth, because honestly I was just trying to find a clever way to make my code a bit more elegant.  I've decided to simply rewrite the virtual method for each derivative according to what it needs, because it's actually less complicated than properly implementing CRTP.  Thank you for your well-explained suggestions, though!

Comment: @sgbrown CRTP solution augmented to support a fixed set of types passed to `doWork`, and unlimited types of `Der`, with the boilerplate in a CRTP intermediate class.

Comment: @sgbrown That's fine. Just a quick hint: the CRTP still uses a templated base class, so if you're trying to provide an interface, you'll need to but an `iBase` non-templated interface class, and have `Base` inherit from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you might want is the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

```
template<class D>
struct Base {
  D* self() { return static_cast<D*>(this); }
  D const* self() const { return static_cast<D*>(this); }
  template<class T>
  void doWork(T b) {
    self()->a += b;
  }
};
struct DerA : public Base<DerA> {
  int a;
};
struct DerB : public Base<DerB> {
  double a;
};
```

Here we pass the derived type to our base class.  Within the base class, you can use `self()->` to access fields in the derived type.  This allows basically full access to the derived type, while letting us share code in the base class.

Note that you cannot pass `DerA` and `DerB` around as a `Base` this way.  If you want that, you need a `virtual` method `doWork`, and `virtual` `template` methods don't exist.

CRTP stands for the curiously repeating template pattern, which I imagine is named because it is strange, it involves repeating a type, and it keeps on showing up in strange corners as being useful.

---

Type erasure probably won't work either, as you want to dispatch the type erasure from two different spots in the code base (the double dispatch problem: you need a centralized list of types supported to do the type Cartesian product on).

To expand on that, in order to support `a+=b` where both `a` and `b` are arbitrary types, you would have to expand over all types twice over, including types that are never mutually visible at the same spot in a compilation unit.  That isn't possible.

---

If you need a common base, and there are only some types you pass to `doWork`, here is how you do it:

```
struct Base {
  virtual void doWork( double ) = 0;
  virtual void doWork( int ) = 0;
  virtual void doWork( long long ) = 0;
};

template<class D>
struct Base_helper:Base {
  D* self() { return static_cast<D*>(this); }
  D const* self() const { return static_cast<D*>(this); }
  template<class T>
  void doWork_impl(T b) {
    self()->a += b;
  }
  void doWork( double x ) override { doWork_impl(x); };
  void doWork( int x ) override { doWork_impl(x); };
  void doWork( long long x ) override { doWork_impl(x); };
};
struct DerA : public Base_helper<DerA> {
  int a;
};
struct DerB : public Base_helper<DerB> {
  double a;
};
```

note that every version of `doWork` must be valid to call on each of the `Der`s, as the `Base_helper` instantiates all of them.

If the kind of type passed to `doWork` is unbounded, yet the types of `Der` is bounded, you can do something like the above only backwards.  It gets awkward, however.  Your best bet in that kind of situation is to use a `boost::variant` type solution.

Comment: Wow, that's some really interesting code!  Kind of...CRTP on steroids.  Thanks a lot for sharing, I think I might use this solution.

Comment: @sgbrown for even more power, `self()->doWork_impl(x);` inside `doWork` instead of `doWork_impl(x)` lets the `DerX` classes optionally override `doWork_impl`, and get it statically dispatched to.  If they don't, then `Base_helper::doWork_impl` is called.  Basically we are type-erasing ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to achieve something like this:

```
template<typedef T>
class Base {
    T a;
    void doWork(T b) { // Add another value to "a" which is of its same type
        a += b; // For example; an operation that works on "a", no matter what numeric type it is
    }
}

class DerA : public Base<int> {
}

class DerB : public Base<float> {
}
```

Or you can dump classes DerA and DerB entirely and use typedefs instead:

```
typedef Base<int> DerA;
typedef Base<float> DerB;
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily solved with a [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)-like pattern:

```
template<class D> // Base class is templated
class Base {
public:
    D a;
    void doWork(D b) {
        a += b;
    }
};

class DerA : public Base<int> {};

class DerB : public Base<float> {};
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://ideone.com/O1s2yp)</kbd>

Edit: in case you need only one common base (`Base<int>` is a completely different type from `Base<float>`) you might use an interface class and have Base inherit from it.

Comment: But then `DerA` and `DerB` both have two different base classes.

Comment: OP asked for a 'derived version of the base class'. I'm adding another CRTP-like detail anyway

Comment: This is probably the best method to deal with my problem, thank you!  Unfortunately, I DO need them to inherit from a common base, and it's not really worth uprooting all of my existing code to simply add an inheriting class for this one small problem (easier to just rewrite a virtual method for each derivative :P ).  However, if other people have a similar problem, I think this is the best solution, being an interesting take on CRTP.  Thanks once again!